# How to resolve error 91 when running code to populate list box selection in userform into excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have a form that contains a list box and I'm trying to write the code to populate the selected items (multiple selection) from the list box into the excel sheet. I got error 91 (object variable or with block variable not set). Below is the part of the code that had the error. In specific, it referred to: For x = 0 To lstCategory.ListCount - 1

```
Sub Submit()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim Itemsselected As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lstCategory As ListBox
   iRow = [Counta(Database!B:B)] + 1

    Set lstCategory = InvestorForm.lstCategory

    With lstCategory
        For x = 0 To lstCategory.ListCount - 1
            If lstCategory.Selected(x) = True Then
            Itemsselected = Itemsselected & lstCategory.List(x) & ", "
            End If
        Next x
    End With
```

I tried adding a "." between "list" and "count" and it didn't resolve the error. I'm simply trying to get the data selected by the user from the list box to appear in the sheet cell.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the revised code below which I have added comments to. Basically, you are going through a bunch of unnecessary steps. I would also recommend you read the help for the `With` statement. You do not need to reference the assigned object within that block as it defeats the whole purpose of the `With` statement itself.

```
Sub Submit
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim Itemsselected As String
    Dim x As Long
'    Dim lstCategory As Listbox         <<-- Not Required
   iRow = [Counta(Database!B:B)] + 1

'    Set lstCategory = InvestorForm.lstCategory         <<-- Not Required

'   Change the With..End block to reference the listbox directly.
    With InvestorForm.lstCategory
        For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1     '<<-- Changed
            If .Selected(x) = True Then      '<<-- Changed
            Itemsselected = Itemsselected & .List(x) & ", "     '<<-- Changed
            End If
        Next x
    End With
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I changed the with statement part to this:  For x = 0 To InvestorForm.lstCategory.ListCount - 1
        If InvestorForm.lstCategory.Selected(x) = True Then
        Itemsselected = Itemsselected & InvestorForm.lstCategory.List(x) & ", "
        End If
        Next x

Comment: You should really go with the `With ... End With` construct. It is far more efficient. Every time you reference an object it needs to be resolved before any action can be performed against it. In this case, each iteration of the `For ... Next` loop requires `InvestorForm` and `lstCategory` to be resolved twice. Using `With ... End With` means that `InvestorForm` and `lstCategory` only need to be resolved once. This can be significant if you have a lot of items in the listbox. It also makes the code more readable.